# Como incluir palavras sem acento nos resultados de uma busca - PHP, MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, acentuação, collation

Por favor, estou precisando de um pouquinho da sapiência e da paciência de vocês.
Estou desenvolvendo um site, que tem uma página de busca, e preciso fazer com que os resultados apresentados sejam "accent insensitives".
Ou seja, se a pessoa digitar "João", o resultado precisa aparecer, e se a pessoa digitar "Joao", o resultado também precisa aparecer.
Entendo que este é um problema antigo, com centenas de posts na Web, falando à respeito, com centenas de soluções propostas.
O problema é que já tentei de tudo, e as palavras sem acentuação, não aparecem nos resultados, de jeito nenhum.
O site é em PHP e o Banco de dados é original do VestaCp, MariaDb.
O Banco de dados, está com Charset UTF8, e o collation utf8_unicode_ci.
Já alterei o Charset para Latin1, e o collation para latin1.swedish.ci, já deixei como UTF8/utf8_general_ci, e com as tabelas todas com o mesmo charset e collation, mas tudo deu na mesma.
As páginas todas estão com UTF-8, inclusive já tive o cuidado de refazer arquivo PHP, com encoding UTF8.
E para minha chateação, o resultado é SEMPRE o mesmo.
Se eu digito com acento, a busca retorna OK, se eu busco sem o acento, não retorna nada.
Tanto faz se eu uso ao fazer o update utf8_encode($string), e depois utf8_decode($string).
Não muda nada, pois as palavras são acentuadas corretamente no resultado.
Ou seja, é SÓ um problema de buscar sem palavras acentuadas.
Ahhh, já tentei usar utf8mb4, e também não funcionou.
Já tentei utilizar uma função "tiraacentos", apesar de ser uma solução provisória, mas não consegui, pois a função precisaria funcionar também, no banco de dados, e mesmo tentando tratar o resultado, que vem do banco, não consegui, porque ele apresenta caracteres especiais e não letras acentuadas.
Ex. "SÃ£o Paulo", não dá para substituir , porque a função não trás o "£" e diversos outros caracteres especiais (ainda assim, seria uma solução horrível).
Já configurei a conexão, o Name, tudo como mysqli utf8, e nada adiantou, não tem erro mas não funciona.

```
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysqli_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysqli_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

Já inclui o callate, na própria busca, e aí piora tudo, pois não há resultado, nem com palavras acentuadas

```
SELECT * FROM imoveis WHERE imovel_cidade LIKE _utf8 "%São Paulo%' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Já tentei alterar o Collate da tabela para utf8_unicode_ci_ai, e o banco de dados não deixa.
Alguém teria, por favor alguma outra dica, para que eu possa tentar implementar e resolver essa questão?
Agradeço muito, qualquer dica!
Obrigado!